# jQuery hover firing without mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element with id=message1mark. The following code will run the two alerts when the page loads regardless of the position on the mouse. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#message1mark").hover(alert("on"), alert("off"));
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap those alerts in functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#message1mark").hover(function(){alert("on");}, function(){alert("off");});
});
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/eJzKr/**

Answer (score 1):

What you tried would be interpreted as

1. try to call a function  (which is why `alert()` is executed at the time of binding
2. and bind its result as a handler   (which is nothing in this case)

---

```
 $("#message1mark").hover(function(){

    alert("on")

}, function(){

    alert("off")

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
jQuery("#message1mark").hover(function() {
        alert("on");
    }, 
       function() {
        alert("off")) 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the alert() function fires automatically on each page.  So even though you've tried to make it dependent on the hover function, it doesn't care.

It sounds like what you want is fundamentally a tooltip functionality.  Some of the techniques listed in these resources might be a better way to approach things.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/jquery/PopupOnHover.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing in two different functions you can include in one function itself. Below is the code for reference.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#message1mark").hover(function(){alert("on");alert("off");});
});
```